# Android: Add and Remove items to Listview from a List

Tags: android, listview

I'm building a calculator application for a board game.
The application contains list of all lands that available to the player, the application should able to add and remove items from the player's list.

Side note: the application should calculate the profit for the player based on the lands that the player has in hand.

[Player View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaUP3.png)
[Lands View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yJAB.png)
I'd like to able to add lands to the players from the lands list when the user click on the add button and remove lands from the player when remove button is clicked. Based on selected items from each list.

Note: I'm using the same adapter to list the projects in the player and lands view

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView ProjectsLV;
private ProjectAdapter Adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton add_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_fab);
    add_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Add Project", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton remove_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.remove_fab);
    remove_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Remove Projects", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Player Player = (Player)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Player");

    ArrayList<Project> Projects = (ArrayList<Project>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Projects");
    Adapter = new ProjectAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Player.getProjects());

    ProjectsLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ProjectsListView);
    ProjectsLV.setAdapter(Adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: You are passing data to adapter from Player.getProjects(), to add or remove any item from list you will have to perform that action on this array and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some lines with my own style on how to do it, you can follow the same way in order to achieve what you want but i will explain in details what happened.
First I created a field `projectList` so i can access it everywhere inside the class and after adding or removing items from this list you just need to call the `notifyDataSetChange()` on your adapter which will update the listview you have. I hope this is good enough.

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Project> projectsList;
private ListView ProjectsLV;
private ProjectAdapter Adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton add_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_fab);


    FloatingActionButton remove_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.remove_fab);


    Player Player = (Player)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Player");

    ArrayList<Project> Projects = (ArrayList<Project>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Projects");
    projectsList = Plyaer.getProjects();
    Adapter = new ProjectAdapter(getApplicationContext(), projectsList);

    ProjectsLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ProjectsListView);
    ProjectsLV.setAdapter(Adapter);
    add_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Add Project", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            // create the new project and call the addProjectToList method;
            prjectsList = addProjectToList(projectsList,project);
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
        }
    });
    remove_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Remove Projects", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            // choose the project to remove and call the removeProjectFromList method;
            removeProjectFromList(projectsList,project);
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChange();
        }
    });

}
    private List<Project> addProjectToList(List<Project> projectsList,Project project){
        projectsList.add(project);
        return projectsList;
    }
    private List<Project> removeProjectFromList(List<Project> projectsList,Project project){
        projectsList.remove(project);
        return projectsList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! but I have a question, how do I get the selected from the both list (player and project list)

Comment: @NasserX projectLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){  ...... this will give you position of the clicked item in the onitemclick method then you can extract player and object by their index

Comment: @greenapps will delete the comment then

Comment: @greenapps what is the way to teach new users about upvote and accepting answers then ?

Comment: You dont have to teach them. They will see. But you can do it for others of course.

Comment: I've renamed the object project to selectedProject and added ProjectsLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectedProject =(Project) (ProjectsLV.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

Comment: this is the way to do it

Comment: I'm able to remove the project but the user has to click on the item from the list to update the selectedProject to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Class

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView ProjectsLV;
private ProjectAdapter Adapter;
private ArrayList<Project> PlayerProjectList;
private Project selectedProject;
private ArrayList<Project> Projects;
private Player Player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton add_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_fab);
    FloatingActionButton remove_fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.remove_fab);

    Player = (Player)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Player");

    Projects = (ArrayList<Project>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Projects");
    PlayerProjectList = Player.getProjects();

    Adapter = new ProjectAdapter(getApplicationContext(), PlayerProjectList);

    ProjectsLV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ProjectsListView);
    ProjectsLV.setAdapter(Adapter);

    ProjectsLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedProject =(Project) (ProjectsLV.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }
    });

    add_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Add Project", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            // create the new project and call the addProjectToList method;
            PlayerProjectList = addProjectToList(PlayerProjectList, selectedProject);
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    remove_fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Remove Projects", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            // choose the project to remove and call the removeProjectFromList method;
            removeProjectFromList(PlayerProjectList, selectedProject);
            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<Project> addProjectToList(ArrayList<Project> projectsList,Project project){
    projectsList.add(project);
    return projectsList;
}
private ArrayList<Project> removeProjectFromList(ArrayList<Project> projectsList,Project project){
    projectsList.remove(project);
    return projectsList;
}
```

}

Comment: Would be better if I added a checkbox into the project list? would have to create a different adapter for the project because the adapter that I'm using is being used ti display the list of project to the user to read from it and shouldn't be changed by the user.